# Can bad certificate downgrade webservice performance?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, iis-7, web-services

I noticed webservice performance downgraded after certificate got expired.
However webservice-client app developed in a way to ignore possible certificate problems.

Is that possible that bad certificate can cause webservice-client app performance downgraded  ? Can somebody point me on MSDN article confirming that ?

Update : I'm more  interested from webservice-client app performance point of view.

For example: if client app (with patch to skip certificate errors) consuming web-service, will it work slower if certificate is expired ?

I suspected there will  be some milliseconds on re-handshake or anything like that on every request if certificate is wrong.

Comment: The performance of your webservice has nothing to do with your certificate being intrusted/expired or whatever status you mean by "bad"

Comment: So if client app consuming web-service (with patch to skip cert errors), it will work the same speed if certificate is expired or not ? I suspected there will  be some milliseconds or re-handshake or anything like that on every request if certificate is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In technical manner it may not downgrade webservice performance but it can in general manner. Certificate expiry or non-trusted certificate will cause warning message in the browsers which can lead normal visitor to leave the website with the assumption of dead/sick website.

We can't assume that all visitors coming to the site, will have technically background to understand and proceed on the website.

> **Helpful resources:**
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727098.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb614564(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996415.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for links! However I'm more  interested from performance point of view, For example if client app consuming web-service, will it work slower if certificate is expired.

Comment: I don't think that will make it slow.